# AWS s3fs - CentOS 6.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have successfully installed s3fs from google code

```
http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/downloads/list
```

I have configured and created a mount point in the system, my mount point is:

```
/mnt/aws
```

the problem is that it mount correctly but if I do the following operation

```
touch /mnt/aws/test.txt
```

it doesn't work, the output of the command is:

```
touch: setting times of `/mnt/aws/test.txt': Operation not permitted
```

also if I launch a "dir" command inside /mnt/aws the output is:

```
dir: reading directory .: Operation not permitted
```

all of this is very strange since the access key id and secret access key are the same I am using with Cyberduck and on Cyberduck I can open my bucket, browse it, upload, download, delete and do whatever I want.

I really don't understand where I'm failing.
Any help is really appreciated

Thanks in advance Marco.

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend against `s3fs`. Its not that it can't work, but it creates the expectation that the mount is a block device when it isn't.

S3 stores files as complete objects. Operations are on the object in its entirety. This is in contrast to a disk volume where operations are done on blocks.

As such, certain tools and operations don't work well with s3fs. Under the covers, files accessed on s3fs are actually cached locally on the disk.

Comment: Hi datasage,thanks for your answer. I have created meanwhile another vps to test if maybe I had missed some steps during installation. I followed this tutorial "http://www.curvve.com/blog/servers/2013/install-s3fs-and-fuse-on-centos-6-rhel-and-mount-s3-drive-on-ec2/". After install and configure I was able to mount the S3 disk and browsing from root account and of course create, delete, upload files. The problem now is that only root can do this operations, infact if I try to do same tasks from other users account it give me error: "touch: sett... Operation not permitted"

Comment: Here some information related to that: https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=321

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to take a look at the new project RioFS (Userspace S3 filesystem): https://github.com/skoobe/riofs. This project is “s3fs” alternative, the main advantages comparing to “s3fs” are: simplicity, the speed of operations and bugs-free code. Currently [the project](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) is in the “testing” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time.

We are seeking for more people to join our project and help with the testing. From our side we offer quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

Hope it helps you and we are looking forward to seeing you joined our community !

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your answer, RioFS appear to be good and i downloaded it to have a try, does it support CentOS? because on compyle I get this error: configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.32.1 fuse >= 2.8.4 libevent >= 2.0 libxml-2.0 >= 2.6 libcrypto >= 0.9) were not met:

No package 'glib-2.0' found
Requested 'fuse >= 2.8.4' but version of fuse is 2.8.3
No package 'libevent' found

Comment: Hello, could you please create a new ticket on GitHub project's page ? Please specify your CentOS distribution version, I'll take a look today and provide you instructions how to install on CentOS. Thank you !

Comment: I have both package installed in my system: [Installed Packages
libevent.i686] and [Installed Packages
glib.i686] and also for Fuse program say I have 2.8.4 while instead I have 2.9.3 with command [pkg-config --modversion fuse] output is [2.9.3]

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of CentOS distributive is it and is it 32bit or 64bit ? (you could get this information by running  `uname -a` )  Thank you !

Comment: Hi Paul this is the version '2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Jun 12 01:01:27 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux' is a 32 bit release

Comment: Great, thanks! will update you when I have instructions for CentOS.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul, I'll wait for them.

Comment: I've updated the instruction on GitHub page, please follow these steps  to install dependencies on Centos. Also, if you find any bug / issue, please report it on GitHub project's page. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you very much Paul, I'll follow the guide and test with riofs, I'll let you know. Regards Marco

Comment: Hi Paul, I've tried also with RioFS, locally it works perfectly with a VPS I have created on the fly, but when it come to install online it install correctly and after execute mount commant it come with the following error:

Failed to execute HTTP request !
Failed to get bucket ACL! Most likely you provided wrong AWS keys or bucket name!

I suspect his maybe the same cause that is blocking s3fs, there is a way I can debug rioFS to deeply know what is the issue? Thanks in advance Marco

Comment: Could you please run riofs with -v -f flags and send me what does it have in "Message" text which is printed just before "Failed to execute HTTP request" ?

Comment: Sure Paul, here it is: <Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message><MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>900000</MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds><RequestId>89345FF117E23536</RequestId><HostId>GqT235yKLtO+n18Hh34SkG6hFSSWhwy0CsuhKLPOvo8qefk3sWEf346PMNiTIdR8r</HostId><RequestTime>Thu, 01 Aug 2013 10:49:43 GMT</RequestTime><ServerTime>2013-08-01T08:53:16Z</ServerTime></Error>

Comment: Looks like your computer's clock is incorrect, please use NTP service to setup the correct time.

Comment: Paul it works perfectly!!! Thank you very much for the suggestion, hope this would be useful also for other users that maybe had my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the site of [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) it has some ways to save the access key:

> Specify your Security Credentials (Access Key ID & Secret Access Key)
>   by one of the
>
> Following methods:
>
> - Passwd_file using the command line option
> - Setting the aAWSACCESSKEYID and AWSSECRETACCESSKEY environment variables
> - Using a .passwd-s3fs file in your home directory
> - Using the system-wide etc/passwd-s3fs file

1. Which of these are you using?
2. Do you have any restriction of IAM on this bucket?

**Other considerations:**

if you want to download / upload content to the bucket, I strongly recommend the use of [s3funnel](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Python/1684).

He works with multithreaded which greatly accelerates the process.

Comment: Hi rmsys, thank you very much for your answer. While I'm trying also with Paul suggestion using RioFS, I just want to share a couple of updated with you to allow understand where is the issue with s3fs. Thinking that I maybe have done some mistake I have installed from scratch CentOS 6 64bit on 3 VPS. 2 local VPS s3fs installed successfully and run correctly I can read and write. On the dedicated server of the ISP installed also from scratch, s3fs mount but cannot read or cannot write error is: touch: setting times of `/mnt/testaws/test.txt': Operation not permitted. This is frustrating!